# JavaFX WebView and jQuery .on() not working

Tags: jquery, webview, javafx

I have this small piece of JS:

```
$('.tab').on( "click", function() {
    renderTabContents($(this).text());
});
```

The html file with this JS is loaded into the webview correctly, yet the code doesn't work. It does work, however, when I load the site in Chrome.... any ways I could make this work in JavaFX too?

And I also noticed that addClass is not working...

Comment: check what `$('.tab')` is returning. Make sure that `$('.tab')` is not returning an empty array. Also you can use (Visual Event)[http://sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event+2] to check if the element is having any events attached.

Comment: It returns an [object Object] every time, just as it should.. How should I go about running visual event in javafx??

Comment: instead of `alert($('.tab'))` try `console.dir($('.tab'))`, this will print the object in your javascript console. Regarding visual event follow the instructions given in that link.

Comment: Cerlin, may I remind you, that javafx WebEngine does NOT have a console. How the heck am I supposed to see the output?? Haven't found any hooks to tie into aswelll :/

Comment: sry i know nothing about `javafx WebEngine`, but you can try alerting some properties like `alert($('.tab').html())` or `alert($('.tab')[0].innerHTML)`.

Comment: I got it! It's the way i programmatically added a test tab from javafx.. have to work with that, solved-ish now :)